# Why does CakePHP still use tabs for indent?

Tags: cakephp

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/contributing/cakephp-coding-conventions.html

I assume this was old, but the `v3` branch still uses tabs also. Does anyone know why the newer version doesn't ahere to something like PSR-2?

Comment: The question is: Why aren't the others not already using it? PSR-2 is retarded concerning how to correctly indent code. Only Tabs should be used for it. Cake will probably not change that (which is a good thing). And the rest out there will hopefully one day come to their senses.

Comment: I agree with @mark. In the end, just use whatever the original repo was using. It will likely never change and certainly doesn't matter aside from being PSR-2 "compliant".

Comment: Funny to get a notification, come back to this question, especially now that CakePHP 3 uses PSR2 :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### PSR-2 is not a standard

[PSR-2](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-2-coding-style-guide.md) is a style *guide* it is not a standard - and even if it were, it's voluntary.

### Why not follow PSR-2

Leaving aside any tab-v-spaces war, changing whitespace project wide for CakePHP has the following advantages:

- Match PSR-2

It brings with it the following disadvantages:

- Zero performance or functional benefit
- Inconvenience merging branches
- Merge conflicts and general pain building releases

The last two points are significant - CakePHP has already gone though various automated formatting-related changes, and each time it has lead to time spent/lost coping with merge conflicts whilst building release, or attempting to backport a fix from one version to another.

These are some of the reasons why following this particular rule of PSR-2 isn't likely to occur any time soon.

Comment: I know the CakePHP team uses code sniffer. I can only imagine how spaces would be a pain to account for. Tabs seem to make more sense to me when using code sniffer. It keeps things more tidy IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this post by Jeff Atwood will help: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/04/death-to-the-space-infidels.html

Comment: Great article. I'll have to read some of the papers too. Thanks.